# Umbraco Cast "IPublishedContent" type to "CustomModel" type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, umbraco

I am testing Umbraco and trying to set up a list of blogs on a page. I have a custom BlogMode.cs which looks like this:

```
public class BlogPostModel : RenderModel
{
    public BlogPostModel() : base(UmbracoContext.Current.PublishedContentRequest.PublishedContent)
    {
    }

    public string MainBlogImage { get; set; }
    public string ImageAltText { get; set; }
    public string Introduction { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<IPublishedContent> BlogPosts { get; set; }
}
```

This works fine as nor my Model will have the properties above. Now what I am trying to do is get all the blog post by using this:

```
var posts = Model.Content.Children.ToList();
```

But what this does is creates a list of type `IPublishedContent`. So now I can not use `Model.Introduction` or `Model.ImageAltText` or any other property in my blog model because it is of type `IPublishedContent`

How would I get this collection and make it of type `BlogModel`?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? My guess you want to display a list of blogs on a page with Title, Introduction and a Link.

Comment: Yes Tej, something like that, trying to get custom properties by using something like `Model.Introduction`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fast Forward 2019:**

These days I'd use the baked in Umbraco ModelsBuilder.  It will generate the strongly typed models for you out of the box, with enough extension points to be able to customise those models as well as where and how they are generated.

For more information, take a look at the ModelsBuilder wiki on GitHub:

https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/Zbu.ModelsBuilder/wiki/Umbraco.ModelsBuilder

**Original Answer circa 2015:**

My recommendation is to use Ditto - there's a Nuget package available and allows you to write code like this:

```
var posts = Model.Content.Children.As<BlogPostModel>();
```

You'll find documentation on Ditto here: https://github.com/leekelleher/umbraco-ditto and there's also lots of information about it in blog posts etc.

Basically, you write yourself a Model and then can map it directly using the Ditto `As<Model>()` generic extension method.

Comment: I take it there isnt a way without a extension package?

Comment: Not unless you want to roll your own framework for this... Believe me - something like Ditto is really much easier

Comment: Basically, what Roberts says! There is another solution called ModelsBuilder, but for most sites, Ditto is much simpler and easier to use!

Comment: But model builder generates code automatically, while with ditto you have to write all models manually, which is lot of work I think. I like other answer in thread and that worked for me.

Comment: @KrunalParmar I agree - ModelsBuilder is the way to go these days with most situations.

Comment: Without taking a look, I'd say it's likely it doesn't currently because a lot of the APIs have been re-written, and Ditto hasn't been updated for a while now.  That said, take a look at the ditto project page: https://github.com/umco/umbraco-ditto

Answer (score 8):

Not sure what version of Umbraco you're using but i'm using 7.4.3 (which includes the model builder) and this works for me.

```
var page = umbracoHelper.TypedContent(relatedLink.Internal);
if (page.ContentType.Alias.Equals("editorial"))
{
    var typedPage = (Editorial)page;
    //Your code here, for example 'typedPage.SiteLinkImage'
}
```

The 'Editorial' class was generated by the model builder.

Comment: This is how I'd do it these days as well.  When this question was first posted, ModelsBuilder was relatively unknown.  It's now the defacto standard and baked into every Umbraco install.